# Unable to import DefaultHttpFilters

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm attempting to create a filter to collect metrics related to request fulfillment time in a Scala Play 2.5 app. I am following [this documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters).

It instructs me to create a class that extends `DefaultHttpFilters`. However, I am unable to import this class! `import play.api.http.DefaultHttpFilters` is unrecognized. It occurred to me that I may need to make an addition to `build.sbt`, so I added `filters` to `libraryDependencies` in that file, but still no luck. The truly strange thing is that `import play.api.http.HttpFilters` is recognized. `DefaultHttpFilters` lives in the same package, and in fact implements the `HttpFilters` trait, so I'm rather bamboozled by the fact that the import is unrecognized.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, and please let me know if I can provide any further information to help in diagnosing the issue.

Here is my `build.sbt`:

```
name := """REDACTED"""

version := "1.0.0"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ws,
  filters,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0",
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.187",
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.0" % "test",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.39",
  specs2 % Test
)

unmanagedJars in Compile += file(Path.userHome+"/lib/*.jar")

resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

fork in run := true
```

Here is `plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.jamesward" %% "play-auto-refresh" % "0.0.14")

addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.3.5")
```

Filters are defined in the following way
`app/filters/AccessLoggingFilter.scala`:

```
import javax.inject.Inject

import akka.stream.Materializer
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.mvc.{Filter, RequestHeader, Result}
import play.api.routing.Router.Tags

import scala.concurrent.Future

class AccessLoggingFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer) extends Filter {

  def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    val requestStartTime = System.nanoTime

    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
      val requestedAction = requestHeader.tags(Tags.RouteController) + "." + requestHeader.tags(Tags.RouteActionMethod)
      val requestFulfillmentTime = System.nanoTime - requestStartTime

      Logger.info("Request for " + requestedAction + " resulted in status code " + result.header.status +
        " and had request fulfillment time " + requestFulfillmentTime + " nanoseconds")

      result.withHeaders("Request-Time" -> requestFulfillmentTime.toString)
    }
  }
}
```

And then `app/filters/Filters.scala`:

```
package filters

import javax.inject.Inject

class Filters @Inject() (accessLoggingFilter: AccessLoggingFilter) { }
```

Comment: ACK @NathanielFord

Comment: Where are you defining `filters`? Are you getting errors when you run `sbt` in the command line? Also, what all is defined in your `project/plugins.sbt` file?

Comment: @NathanielFord sorry for posting with incomplete information, and thank you for having a look. I've updated OP with the content of `plugins.sbt` and my filter. Also, I have not been running `sbt` in the command line, because I cannot even import `play.api.http.DefaultHttpFilters`, the class which `Filters` should extend

Comment: @AnonYmous Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`DefaultHttpFilters` was only introduced in Play 2.5.4, and you are using Play 2.5.0.

So change your Play version to 2.5.4 at least (the current version at the time of writing is 2.5.6)

```
// In plugins.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.4")
```

Then, just reload the project and update your dependencies (`activator update`)

If you really need to use that version, use `HttpFilters` instead (same example from "Using filters")

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.http.HttpFilters
import play.filters.gzip.GzipFilter

class Filters @Inject() (
  gzip: GzipFilter,
  log: LoggingFilter
) extends HttpFilters {

   val filters = Seq(gzip, log)
}
```